# How does "knife ec2 server create"'s expansion of --run-list work?

Tags: amazon-ec2, chef-infra

I'm unable to bootstrap my server because "knife ec2 server create" keeps expanding my runlist  to "roles".

```
knife ec2 server create \
    -V \
    --run-list 'role[pgs]' \
    --environment $1 \
    --image $AMI \
    --region $REGION \
    --flavor $PGS_INSTANCE_TYPE \
    --identity-file $SSH_KEY \
    --security-group-ids $PGS_SECURITY_GROUP \
    --subnet $PRIVATE_SUBNET \
    --ssh-user ubuntu \
    --server-connect-attribute private_ip_address \
    --availability-zone $AZ \
    --node-name pgs \
    --tags VPC=$VPC
```

Consistently fails because 'roles[pgs]' is expanded to 'roles'. Why is this? Is there some escaping or alternative method I can use?

I'm currently working around this by bootstrapping with an empty run-list and then overriding the runlist by running chef-client once the node is registered.

Comment: IMO this should work. May be you don't have this role defined on chef-server?

Comment: It's definitely an issue with the expansion of the run list. I've given up and bootstrap with an empty run list now.

Answer (score 0):

This is a feature of bash. [] is a [wildcard expander](http://linuxg.net/bash-wildcards-the-square-brackets-and-the-curly-brackets/). You should can escape the brackets using "\".